# Error with urlFor() on Slim + Twig

Tags: php, twig, slim

I get a error where Slim says

```
Message: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template 
("Named route not found for name: userList") in "sidebar.twig" at line 7.
```

My view is

```
{% extends 'base.twig' %}
{% block title %} Índice {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
    {% include "sidebar.twig" %}
```

My view sidebar.twig is as below:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    <div class="dropdown menu col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-9">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">GESTIÓN DE PARTICIPANTES</a></li>
            {% if authorized %}
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="{{ urlFor('userList') }}">GESTION DE USUARIOS</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

code for view + model

```
$app->get('/users', function() use ($app, $authorized,$users)
{ 
    $app->render('users.twig',array('users' => $users, 'is_admin' => $authorized));
})->name('userList');
```

Code in github is => `https://github.com/Mangulomx/olimpiada`

Comment: Check your routes file is the route name `userList` is defined ? Show code from routes file

Comment: I show it up  $app->get('/users', function() use ($app, $authorized,$users)
{ 
    $app->render('users.html.twig',array('users' => $users, 'is_admin' => $authorized));
})->name('userList');

Comment: Kindly check http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/problems/943-cant-get-twig-extensions-to-work this reply Posted by Brian Nesbitt on Sep 29, 2012 @ 08:44 AM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are not loading the users.php route file anywhere in your project. If this is not loaded then the error is correct as it doesn't know about that route based on the routes loaded. You might want to add ../routes/users.php into public/index.php.